# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime error for textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have a code which adds the users data from front-end. But when submitting the code on button click i m getting the below error

> *String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.*

Please see the code why it is happening.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString);
        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Insert into tbl_teachers_profile (NgoId,first_name, last_name,dob,gender,designation, joining_date,leaving_date,active) values (@NgoId,@first_name, @last_name,@dob,@gender,@designation,@joining_date,@leaving_date,@active)", conn);
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@NgoId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlNgoName.SelectedValue;
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@first_name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtfirstname.Text;
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@last_name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtlastname.Text;
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@dob", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtdateofbirth.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@gender", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlgender.SelectedValue;
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@designation", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtdesgination.Text;
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@joining_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtdoj.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@leaving_date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtdol.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@active", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ddlActiveInactive.SelectedValue);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('page added sucessfully');window.location ='csrteachersprofile.aspx';", true);
        }
    }
```

I tried debugging it and the value was coming as **"";**

Please help

Front end code:-

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtdateofbirth" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddNew" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqdob" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtdateofbirth" ErrorMessage="Date of birth is required" ValidationGroup="AddNew" CssClass="error-class"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: `@joining_date / @leaving_date` have different DB Types, is this correct? What is the value of both text boxes? Have you tried `DateTime.ParseExact` using your expected format?

Comment: @AlexK.: both have `Datetime` datatype. I did not tried `Datetime.ParseExact`

Comment: In your code one is DateTime, the other is VarChar

Comment: @AlexK.: I corrected that and now debugging again. Sorry my mistake it was

Comment: @RahulSutar I mentioned the same in my answer

Comment: @SidM: your code is also not working

Comment: can you tell how do you get `txtdateofbirth.Text`, `txtdoj.Text` and `txtdol.Text`?

Comment: @L16H7: I have used `datepicker` for it.

Comment: then `DateTime.ParseExact` should solve your problem

Comment: On which line you get this error? What are the values on _that_ line and what is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: @SonerGönül: i am getting error at line `cmd1.Parameters.Add("@dob", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtdateofbirth.Text);`. While debuffing i am getting value as `"";`

Comment: @L16H7: can you let me know how ?

Comment: Like this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) : DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "mm/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: @RahulSutar `txtdateofbirth.Text` value is `""`? How do you think you can convert this to a `DateTime`?

Comment: Post your page load code.

Comment: im almost positive your problem is in your page load

Comment: cmd1.Parameters.Add("@leaving_date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtdol.Text); here Sqldbtype is varchar but you convert to datetime could you check this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem is in your aspx html code were you are setting the `ReadOnly` Property.

I suggest you should remove that, and make the change as given below.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtdateofbirth" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddNew" Enabled="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

You also need to make changes in code-behind for all the three textboxes,like below:-

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@dob", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtdateofbirth.Text);
```

Do let me know if it works or not.!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 DateTime.ParseExact(txtdoj.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: same the way u gave, `yyyy/mm/dd`

Comment: i want that, i dont want user to add date through textbox, i am using datepicker for that

Comment: it seems every thing is perfect..Do cross check with datatype of that field in database.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your issue is there is no business logic in between your data logic and UI logic. Your data logic shouldn't be accessing controls directly.

First thing's first though. You have these lines in your code:

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@joining_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtdoj.Text);
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@leaving_date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtdol.Text);
```

I think `leaving_date` should be a DateTime and not VarChar. That's issue #1. Second issue is, what do you want to do in the case of an invalid or blank date? Should it be null in the database if its blank? If so, you need to do something like this:

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@joining_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtdoj.Text) ? System.DBNull.Value : Convert.ToDateTime(txtdoj.Text);
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@leaving_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtdol.Text) ? System.DBNull.Value : Convert.ToDateTime(txtdol.Text);
```

This will check if the date values are null or empty and if they are, it'll pop in a null value for the dates.

You really need to stick a business logic layer in here though. Your UI should be communicating with this business logic layer, which should check the sanity of the data, and if all is good, it calls the data layer.

Comment: @icemanind: `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` is giving error that string does not contain definition

Comment: @RahulSutar - Use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` instead.

Comment: @rushankshah - The problem is, his text calendar value is empty, and so it can't convert it into a date. I can only assume he wants to insert a null.